# Configure interactive keyboard authentication

Tags: linux, ssh, pam

I have a linux machine running OpenSSH Server 4.3.
How can I configure it to use keyboard-interactive authentication - define prompts and responses and so on.

Please be specific, as I am pretty new in this.

**Edit**:

After some googling it appears that PAM (Pluggable authentication module) has to be involved with the process. Now I need to find out what module should be configured there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you are actually trying to accomplish, you will have to look into PasswordAuthentication and/or ChallengeResponseAuthentication, and write your own PAM module. Install and configure e.g. pam_opie to get an idea of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

It mostly depends on your gnu/linux distro, but to start, be sure to write this into `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Comment: Yes, but how do I configure the prompts are responses, what if i want to ask something else besides the password?

Comment: AFAIK "password-interactive" means that you are required to _type_ the password, you can't give it as a parameter (without [fooling](http://www.debianadmin.com/sshpass-non-interactive-ssh-password-authentication.html) ssh).